# the verb agreement for conjunction of plural and singular nouns

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

I wrote:

> When using this technique, **the document** or **segments of a document** **is/are** viewed as plain text.

Should I use *is* or *are* in this sentence?

Comment: I think since the last one is plural, you should go with "are".

Comment: Since you're speaking in generalities, you can change singular **document** to plural "documents" .... *documents and segments of documents are viewed as plain text*.    The general sense supports "and". No native speaker would take that plural to mean that the process handles more than one document concurrently. They would understand the plural to be a form of generalizing: "when this technique is applied to documents and to segments of documents".

Comment: You could also choose the singular with the indefinite article: *...a document or a document segment is viewed....*  Absolutely no reason here to choose the one construction which causes dissonance, a mixed singular-plural compound.

Comment: Using *the* and *a* in your sentence makes me think you all talking about two or more documents.

Answer (score 1):

When a subject is made up of two items joined with *or*
(either...or...) we use a singular verb if the last item is singular (a plural verb is sometimes used in informal English ) and a plural verb if the last item is plural.

> Either a station or a cinema is (are *informal*) a good place to meet.
>   The President or his representatives are to attend the meeting. 
>   When using this technique, the document or segments of a document **are** viewed as plain text.

If the last item is singular and previous item plural,we can use either a singular or plural verb.

> Either the teachers or the principal are /is to blame for the accident.

Comment: you said first *a plural verb if the last item is plural* and then *If the last item is plural and previous item singular, we can use either a singular or plural verb.*, they are contradicted!

Answer (score 0):

When you say "A or B" the verb agrees with B. So, in your sentence it should be "are," which corresponds to "segments of a document."

Comment: Why should it agree with "B"?

Comment: As far as I know, that is the basic rule. For example, if you say "either A or B," the verb also agrees with "B."